# A question about derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos(1/t)dt$

Then$f'(0)=?$

I tried $f'(x)=\cos\left(1/x\right)$, but then I get into trouble.

Hope for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go back to the definition:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\int_0^x\cos(1/t)\,dt.$$
Now the integrand oscillates like crazy near the origin, and it's not unreasonable to guess that the limit will be zero.
To prove it, I suggest the substitution $t=1/s$ in the integral, then use $\lvert\cos s\rvert\le1$. Can you take it from there?

(Edit: Fixed typo in the very first formula.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try integration by parts:
$$
\int_0^x\cos(1/t)dt=-t^2\sin(1/t)|_0^x+2\int_0^xt\sin(1/t)dt.
$$
Both terms are $O(x^2)$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $$
\int_0^x\cos(1/t)dt=t\cos(1/t)|_0^x+\int_0^x \frac{1}{t}\sin(1/t)dt.
$$

Comment: @Bacon I integrated the cosine not 1: $$\cos(1/t) = -t^2\frac{\cos(1/t)}{-t^2}=-t^2\frac{d}{dt}\sin(1/t)$$.

Comment: After I posted that I thought perhaps you'd chosen a different $dv$ in the partial integration. My mistake - Thanks!